# Extends from type parameter

Tags: java, android, inheritance, extends

I am trying to create a generic base class but getting "Cannot extends from its type parameter error"

Here is my class:

```
package com.akturk.bella.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

abstract class BaseActivity<E extends Activity> extends E {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getContentView());
}

@Override
public void onContentChanged() {
    super.onContentChanged();
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
}

protected abstract
@LayoutRes
int getContentView();
}
```

What i want to do is pass a class parameter to extends base class from another class like FragmentActivity or ListActivity or something else that extends Activity.

How can i achive my goal?

**EDIT :**

I want a usage like

`public class TestActivity<FragmentActivity> extends BaseActivity`

or

`public class TestActivity<ListActivity> extends BaseActivity`

By doing this, i would able to use ListActivity or FragmentActivity`s spesific methods like getListView() or getSupportedFragmentManager()

Comment: Looks like you want to extend `Activity` and not `E`. Generics are used to allow your class to define values of the generic type, which seems not to be what you want to do in your code.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you edit your question to provide an overview of what structure you are trying to represent with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve what you want using **subtyping**. Firstly, Java did not support generics from the beginning. To  stay backwards compatible, generic types get **erased** at runtime, so in your case, dynamically, every instance of `E` is replaced by `Activity`, even if you instantiate `BaseActivity<ListActivity>`.

However, you could try achieving something similar using **composition**.

```
abstract class BaseActivity<E extends Activity> {
  public E activity;
  public BaseActivity(E activity){
    this.activity = activity; 
  } 
// ...
}
```

Which provides you an **indirect** access to the methods of the generic activity you pass it. However, this means that you cannot polymorphically put `BaseActivity` where its generic type is required, because it does not subclass it.

Still, what you can do now is (assuming `BaseActivityImpl` is a non-abstract variant of `BaseActivity`):

```
(new BaseActivityImpl<ListActivity>(theListActivityInstance)).activity.getListView()
```

**Edit**: Actually, there is an even more fundamental problem if what you want to achieve would actually work:

```
class Cat<A> extends A {
  String eat(){ return "Cat is eating"; }
}

class Dog {
  void eat(){ System.out.println("Dog is eating"); }
}
```

What would happen if you called `(new Cat<Dog>()).eat();`? `Cat` isn't overriding `eat`, because the signatures do not match.

**Edit2**: Also, if the generic superclass does not provide a default constructor, there would be no way of instantiating it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It was quite clear for me. I think i am going for dirty way and duplicate my BaseActivity class like BaseFragmentActivity and BaseListActivity.